# Angular Regex Split String 1x asd..... 2x asd

Tags: angular, regex, split

I am trying to split a string by [0-9]+ [xX] | [0-9]+[xX], string example:

> 10 x source 4 50° on booms (2 downstage left and right, 2 upstage left and right) 2x festoons (mentioned above) 4x 1kx Fresnel backlight in L712 4x SL 15/32 (3x L443, 4x R119) – all four of which are specifically focused specials 1x Edison bulb suspended from grid

I would like to break the text into seperate lines using a pipe in angular, to display like:

> 10 x source 4 50° on booms (2 downstage left and right, 2 upstage left and right)
> 2x festoons (mentioned above)
> 4x 1kx Fresnel backlight in L712
> 4x SL 15/32 (3x L443, 4x R119) – all four of which are specifically focused specials
> 1x Edison bulb suspended from grid

I have tried to use the following regex but it is including the next 1x in the regex.

```
/([0-9]+[xX] [a-zA-z].*)(?:([0-9]+[xX]))/gm
```

```
Output: 10x source 4 50° on booms (2 downstage left and right, 2 upstage left and right) 2x festoons (mentioned above) 4x 1kx Fresnel backlight in L712 4x SL 15/32 (3x L443, 4x R119) – all four of which are specifically focused specials 1x
```

I would also like to be able to add the option as mentioned in the first sentance to check on two scenarios.

1. 1x asd....
2. 1 x asd....

Then I will split the string using the regex in Angular.

Comment: Please state, in words, at the beginning of your question, the rule that determines where the string is to be split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
/\d+\s*x\b(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()])*?(?=\d+x|$)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNDNpj/2). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `x\b` - `x` and a word boundary
- `(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()])*?` - zero or more (but as few as possible) sequences of a `(` + zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` + `)` or any char but `(` and `)`
- `(?=\d+x|$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with one or more digits and `x` or end of string.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "10 x source 4 50° on booms (2 downstage left and right, 2 upstage left and right) 2x festoons (mentioned above) 4x 1kx Fresnel backlight in L712 4x SL 15/32 (3x L443, 4x R119) – all four of which are specifically focused specials 1x Edison bulb suspended from grid";
const re = /\d+\s*x\b(?:\([^()]*\)|[^()])*?(?=\d+x|$)/gi;
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(text.match(re), 0, 4) + "</pre>"
```